# In MVC how can you retrieve data from a model that is stored as a object in its super model?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am using MVC Razor to try to have a list of links appear down the left side of the screen and be clickable which will then retrieve data from that model and be displayed in a separate section of the screen. In this view I store models for Office, Computers and Monitors in a super model class called OCM.cs Shown below:

```
##OCM.cs##

    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;

    namespace WebApplication2.Models
    {
        public abstract class OBJECT
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int Type { get; set; }
        public string Name1 { get; set; }
    }
    public class Office:OBJECT
    {

        public string OfficeLocation { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public int NumComputers { get; set; }
        public int NumMonitors { get; set; }
    }
    public class Computer:OBJECT
    {

        public String LastUser { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public int NumMonitors { get; set; }
        public String TotalHDSpace { get; set; }
        public String FreeHDSpace { get; set; }
        public int NumUpdates { get; set; }
    }
    public class Monitor:OBJECT
    {

        public String Manufacturer { get; set; }
        public String ModelID { get; set; }
        public String SerialNum { get; set; }
        public int HoursON { get; set; }
        public String LastTestTime { get; set; }
        public String LastTestType { get; set; }
      }
    }
```

After this I created a hardcoded OBJECT list because I have not attached a database yet.

```
##Controller for view for CompAndMonitors##
  public ActionResult CompAndMon()
    {
        var ObjectList = new List<OBJECT>{
                        new Office() {Type =  1,ID = 1, Name1 = "Fort Collins", Name = "Fort Collins", Email = "pasty@gmail.com", Phone = "555-123-5555", NumComputers = 1, NumMonitors = 1, OfficeLocation = "Fort Collins"} ,
                        new Computer() {Type =  2,ID = 2,Name1 = "Speed-Machine", Name = "Speed-Machine", LastUser = "Ted", NumMonitors = 1, FreeHDSpace = "12GB", NumUpdates = 0, TotalHDSpace = "50GB" } ,
                        new Monitor() {Type =  3, ID = 3, Name1 = "Sony", Manufacturer = "Sony", HoursON = 20, LastTestTime = "11pm, August 31", LastTestType = "SMPTE", ModelID = "654123", SerialNum = "a36-f45-gh325"} ,
                        new Office() {Type =  1, ID = 4, Name1 = "Denver", Name = "Denver", Email = "pasty@gmail.com", Phone = "555-123-5555", NumComputers = 2, NumMonitors = 3, OfficeLocation = "Denver"} ,
                        new Computer() {Type =  2, ID = 5, Name1 = "Nicks PC", Name = "Nick's PC", LastUser = "Ted", NumMonitors = 1, FreeHDSpace = "12GB", NumUpdates = 0, TotalHDSpace = "50GB"  } ,
                        new Monitor() {Type =  3, ID = 6, Name1 = "LG", Manufacturer = "LG", HoursON = 20, LastTestTime = "11pm, August 31", LastTestType = "SMPTE", ModelID = "654123", SerialNum = "a38-l87kp-g6j9"} ,
                        new Computer() {Type =  2, ID = 7, Name1 = "Ted", Name = "FastOne", LastUser = "Ted", NumMonitors = 2, FreeHDSpace = "23GB", NumUpdates = 2, TotalHDSpace = "50GB"  } ,
                        new Monitor() {Type =  3, ID = 8, Name1 = "HTC", Manufacturer = "HTC", HoursON = 20, LastTestTime = "11pm, August 31", LastTestType = "SMPTE", ModelID = "654123", SerialNum = "d77-ko9-poo77" },
                        new Monitor() {Type =  3, ID = 9, Name1 = "Panisonic", Manufacturer = "Panisonic",HoursON = 20, LastTestTime = "11pm, August 31", LastTestType = "SMPTE", ModelID = "654123", SerialNum = "h67-j567-lo99" }
         };

        return View(ObjectList);
    }
```

After this I use a foreach loop to display the list of OBJECTS on the left side of the screen. I display them by the name of the object in an 'a' tag. I put the action onclick inside of the 'a' tag to hopefully pass the model data to a java script function which will then display that information on another part of the screen. Is there a way to get the information(SerialNumber, Manufacturer, FreeHDSpace, etc..) stored in the Office Computer or Monitor from the list of OBJECT model given to the view?

```
##View CompAndMon##
    @model IEnumerable<WebApplication2.Models.OBJECT>
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "CompAndMon";
    }
    <script>
    //I would like the function to look something like this 
       function getItem(Model){
      //though I know this next line is not possible
           var text = "this is the Serial Number" + @Model.SerialNum;
           document.getElementBtId("displaytab").innerHTML = text;
       }
    </script>
      @foreach (var item in Model)
      {   
           if (@item.Type == 1)
           {
               <p>
                    <a onclick="getItem(@item ) ">
                        @item.Name1
                    </a>
               </p>
           }
           else if (@item.Type == 2)
           {
                <p>&ensp;&ensp;
                    <a onclick="getItem(@item)">
                         @item.Name1
                    </a>
                </p>
           }
           else
           {
                <p>&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;
                    <a onclick="getItem(@item)">
                        @item.Name1
                    </a>
                </p>
           }
    }
    <div id="displaytab" class="container col-lg-11 col-lg-offset-1">
                    Select a computer or monitor and the information about the device or loaction will be displayed here.
                </div>
```

Comment: You must first cast to the child type before you can access its properties. e.g. `if(item is Office) { var location = ((Office)item).OfficeLocation; }`

Comment: cant do that because the Office class is not included by OBJECT namespace

Comment: Add `@using WebApplication2.Models` so you can access all the short model names in your view. Otherwise, you'll need to specify the full namespace for the classes.

Comment: is there any reason why I wouldn't be able to pass these variables that I created as you said above to a javascript function? When I inspect the element it shows that the objects are being passed correctly for the different objects, but the onclick doesn't run the function with these variables @Jasen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this (for example for "computers") by casting them to their specific classes:

```
var office = item as Office;
var computer = item as Computer;
var monitor = item as Monitor;
if (office != null)
{
     <p>
          <a onclick="getItem(@item ) ">
               @item.Name1, @office.OfficeLocation;    <== office "knows" properties
           </a>
     </p>
}
```

Sidenote: Perhaps the `Type` property is not needed anymore.

Comment: it wont let me cast them because Office, Computer and Monitor are not included by OBJECT namespace.    `code`model IEnumerable<WebApplication2.Models.OBJECT>`code`   @rboe

Comment: This works is you include `@using WebApplication2.Models`, but will not let me pass these variables to the javascript function i am using after

Answer (score 0):

You should just create an `abstract` method/property in `OBJECT` class, which will generate the title/text you need and simply override that in derived class. What you are trying to do (with type checking) violates the OOP rules.